# Realm studio can't open new realm file generated from nodejs realm v6.1.1

Tags: realm

I'm trying to convert my json data to a .realm file, i think i'm succeeding since i see the default.realm file increasing size but when i try to open it using realm studio i get this error:

[image]

I'm not sure what to do at this point. The realm/realm mongodb realm sync names are very confusing and links to docs go from one product to another which makes it a lot more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Realm is in the process of a change from Realm to MongoDB Realm

The first, I call 'classic' Realm. That's going be be Realm 5.x SDK and Realm Studio 3.11.

The Beta version of MongoDB Realm is what you're using (I think) and it's SDK is 10.x and that goes with Realm Studio 10.x. They work together and the SDK's are not compatible with the other Realm Studio versions.

So, if you are using the Beta, you'll need to download [Realm Studio 10.x.](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases)

Be sure to back up important data files as opening them with a newer version will update them and you can't go backward.