# Opening Realm files of format version 11 is not supported by this version of Realm on Mac

Tags: swift, realm, realm-studio

Already saved my data to Local Realm DB. But can't read it with Realm Studio. Also can't read it with Realm Browser. Realm Browser asking for encryption key with 128-hex value.
[image]

Comment: It's a good idea to do some research before posting questions. It can save a bunch of time. See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63913088/realm-studio-cant-open-new-realm-file-generated-from-nodejs-realm-v6-1-1/63962140#63962140) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993503/cannot-open-default-realm-file-using-realm-studio-or-realm-browser). Also, Realm Browser is a depreciated product and should not be used. Realm Studio is the appropriate replacement for both Realm and MongoDB Realm

Comment: i have all the most current realm and i am getting same sort of error. "Opening Realm files of format version 20 is not supported by this version of Realm."  Big Sur issue?